# How to pass system properties to a jar file

Tags: java, maven, properties, jar, system

I have a main class that expects certain properties that I pass using the -D option. I can access this in my IDE by sending them as VM options.

I package this application into a jar file using Maven and when I try the following:

`java -jar myjar.jar -Denviroment=dev`

or

`java -jar myjar.jar "-Denvironment=dev"`

The enviroment system property is not getting picked up.

Any pointers on what is going on?

Comment: I was able to figure this out. Just so it helps someone else. All I did was to pass the -D before the jar as shown below: java -jar -Denvironment=dev myjar.jar ( not sure how that would make a difference!)

Comment: `-jar myjar.jar` should be added last after all `-D` See below answer

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Pass the arguments before the `-jar`. If you pass them after the jar file they are interpreted as command line parameters and passed to the `String[] args` in `main`. Like,

```
java -Denviroment=dev -jar myjar.jar
```

Comment: This works. I used `sudo java   -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb?useSSL=false -Dspring.datasource.username=root -Dspring.datasource.password=test1234 -jar backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to run spring boot application from command line

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

Adding to Elliott's answer, if I just run this then I get an error:

```
java -Djna.nosys=true -jar jenkins.war
```

but if I add quotes like this then it works:

```
java "-Djna.nosys=true" -jar jenkins.war
```

Comment: another thing to keep in mind is, to NOT use uppercase variable names, for example `-DSPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development` wont work.